# How to prove $u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega^+)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Here is a lemma from Gilbarg-Trudinger *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations* states the following :

> **Lemma 9.12**  Let $u \in W^{1,1}_0(\Omega^{+}), f\in L^p(\Omega^{+}), 1<p<\infty$ satisfy $\Delta u= f$ weakly in $\Omega^{+}$ with $u=0$ near $(\partial \Omega)^{+}$.  Then $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap W^{1,p}_0(\Omega^{+})$ and
> $$||D^2u||_{p;\Omega^{+}} \leq C||f||_{p;\Omega^{+}}.$$

Where $\Omega^{+}$ means $\{x \in \partial \Omega | x_n >0\}$.

At the end of the proof of the lemma, the authors state that

> $\cdots\cdots$. Since $u_h(x',0)=0$, we also obtain $u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega^+)$.

Here $u_h$ is the regularization of $u$.

We know $u=0$ near $(\partial \Omega)^{+}$, so does $u_h$. But $u_h$ only vanish on $x_n=0$, how to obtain $u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega^+)$ ?